# Regex to replace everything between a slash and a space

Tags: regex, oracle

I would like to be able to capture anything between an opening \ and ending space and remove it from the string.

I have the sample text of

```
\viewkind4\uc1d\cf1\lang1033\f0\fs20 This is a test to see if I can pull in documents fr other things.
```

That I'd like to end up like

```
This is a test to see if I can pull in documents fr other things.
```

I'm new to regex, and I am trying to do this in an Oracle query so I tried
`^\\\s$` thinking that I could get the it to find the starting slash and the space between `fs20` and `This is a test....`

Any ideas on what I could try?

Comment: Try: `^\\[^\s]*\s`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(mycolumn, '\\\S+\s', '')
```

Regexp explanation:

```
\\      a backslash
\S+     as many characters as possible others than a space
\s      a space
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=64b77ac803e444d75c50aa082e2b8f69)**:

```
WITH mytable AS (
    SELECT '\viewkind4\uc1d\cf1\lang1033\f0\fs20 This is a test to see if I can pull in documents fr other things.' mycolumn FROM dual
)
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(mycolumn, '\\\S+\s', '') new_column FROM mytable
```

```
| NEW_COLUMN                                                        |
| :---------------------------------------------------------------- |
| This is a test to see if I can pull in documents fr other things. |
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you specified an opening `\`, you indicated to me that you're looking for your first space and then grab everything after that. This works on not just `\` but on any non-space character.

Find the first space and then capture every thing beyond it.

```
WITH mytable AS (
    SELECT '\viewkind4\uc1d\cf1\lang1033\f0\fs20 This is a test to see if I can pull in documents fr other things.' mycolumn FROM dual
)
SELECT    regexp_instr(mycolumn,' ',1) as first_space,  --Now use substr to get everything beyond it.
         substr(mycolumn,regexp_instr(mycolumn,' ',1) +1) as all_past_first_sp
FROM mytable
```